# How to mix-in Paperclip has_attached_file method in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, module, paperclip, mixins

Paperclip provides the following code:

```
has_attached_file :image, 
...
...
```

which is duplicated across several models.

Extracting to a module:

```
module AttachedImage
  include Paperclip::Glue

  has_attached_file :image, 
  ...
  ...
```

raises `Exception encountered: #<NoMethodError: undefined method 'class_attribute' for AttachedImage:Module>` exception.

What does this mean? How to mix-in Paperclip `has_attached_file` code? Is there a better way to eliminate duplication?

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for a similar solution just now and came up with the following:

```
module AttachedFileModule
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
    attr_accessible :avatar

    extend Paperclip::Glue
    has_attached_file :avatar,
    :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" },
      :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
  end
end
```

As you can see in the above code we have to extend `ActiveSupport::Concern` so we can ise the `attr_accessible` method. We must also extend `Paperclip::Glue` so we can use the `has_attached_file` method.

Then in the model you want to attach images to:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include AttachedFileModule
end
```

Comment: I am trying to use this but the paperclip helper object isn't returned when calling the attachment file.  So if I call `User.avatar` it will say method avatar is undefined.  If I add attr_accessor for avatar in the User model then avatar is always nil.  Has anyone gotten this to work?

Comment: Here are a few suggestions: Make sure to save the module in ProjectRoot/lib/attached_file_module.rb

Comment: Verify that 'avatar' is the correct name of the field. I know that I decided to call my field 'image' instead. Are you sure you added the has_attached_file columns to your User model directly? Run 'rails console' and type 'User' to see the attributes of the user model. You should see columns with the name 'avatar_file_name' and 'avatar_content_type'. If you don't see these you probably haven't run your migrations correctly. Link a copy or your users table from db/schema.rb and I can take a look.

Comment: It might be the location of module.  I was trying to use it as a rails 4 model concern.  It's possible that paperclip needs earlier access to the AR load.